# Webform select limit

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there a method to limit the number of chosen select options?
In D7 there was [Webform Select Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_select_limit) but in D8 there is no alternative.

What I want to do is this:
Create a webform for event registration with maximum number op places.

```
NAME: ____ 
EMAIL: _____ 
WORKSHOP: 
 A. Option 1 (maximum 20 places)
 B. Option 2 (maximum 20 places)
 C. Option 3 (no maximum)
 ....

SUBMIT
```

Comment: There isn't. For a quick fix you'll have to solve this on your own with custom jQuery.

Comment: See [Add Webform Options Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3076750).

Comment: This is now a default option in webform. solved